# Форма отправки, не отрабатывает preg_match

Tags: php

День добрый, пишу форму отправки, столнулся с пролемой ucfirst не работает для кирилицы, нашел такое решение `mb_convert_case($setem, MB_CASE_TITLE, 'UTF-8'),` используя его написал функцию провери некоторых полей, preg_match перестал работать! Если убираю эту часть кода!

```
  foreach($_POST as $key => $setem ){
            $_POST[$key] = mb_convert_case($setem, MB_CASE_TITLE, 'UTF-8');
        };
```

То `preg_match` работает! Как можно это решить или проще вставить этот кусок  конвертация первых букв в заглавные после проверки полей?

```
function fieldCHK(){

    foreach($_POST as $key => $setem ){
        $_POST[$key] = mb_convert_case($setem, MB_CASE_TITLE, 'UTF-8');
    };

    if($_POST['email'] == '')  {
  echo "Пусто";
  } else if (!preg_match("/^([a-z0-9_\.-]+)@([a-z0-9_\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})$/",$_POST['email'])) {
  echo "Непавильный ящик";
  } else {
  echo "Дальше";
  }

};
```

Comment: Ок, спасибо!

Comment: или так:

    preg_match("/^([A-Za-z0-9_\.-]+)@([a-z0-9_\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})$/",$_POST['email']);

или вместо preg_match:

    filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)

Answer (score 1):

Вы пробегаетесь по значениям из POST, первые буквы у вас становятся верхнего регистра. А в проверке майла верхний регистр не учитывается, поэтому он у вас всегда возвращает false.

Вам либо нужно не затрагивать поле поле майл, либо сперва проверить, а потом апперкейсить